# how can I get ids from json_decode in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get all ids from json by using json_decode function for this response.How can I get only id in an array? I really appreciate any help.

Response:

```
{
  "columns": [
    "name",
    "id",
    "sno"
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      "test1",
      "123",
      "1"
    ],
    [
      "test2",
      "456",
      "2"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Code:

```
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $val) {
        echo $val;
        if ($k == "id") {
            array_push($all_ids, $val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your quotes are a mess. You need to quit editing in Word.

Comment: Your response is not valid json data so json_decode will return null.

Comment: Sorry updated the json response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$obj     = json_decode($result);
$all_ids = array();

foreach ($obj->data as $el) {
  array_push($all_ids, $el[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it as follows, using [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$obj = json_decode($result);
// identify which column number corresponds to "id"
$idColumnNo = in_array('id', $obj->columns);
// collect the elements at that column number from the data array
$all_ids = array_map(function ($elem) {
    return $elem[$idColumnNo];
}, $obj->data);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$ids = array_map(function($a){return $a[1];}, $obj['data']);
```

Comment: Getting an error with this: *Cannot use object of type stdClass as array*

Comment: @JayBlanchard you're missing the `true` from `$obj = json_decode($result, true);`

Comment: Copied and pasted all of the code, including the `true` still left the error in testing. `true` returns an object which can be gotten like this: `$obj->data`. Changing to that when testing worked perfectly.